# .NET Framework Assemblies in Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a collection of assemblies using reflection.  I want to loop through them, but I would like to ignore the .NET framework or ASP.NET framework DLL's. Is there an attribute on the assembly that marks that its from the .NET framework?  Or any other designation?

I was looking at the name, and if the name of the assembly starts with System, Microsoft, or mscorlib, I am ignoring it.  But I was wondering if there is a flag I can use to make this even easier?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134/determining-if-an-assembly-is-part-of-the-net-framework/3666403#3666403 (Will let @Brian decide if duplicate and/or if VTC makes sense here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134/determining-if-an-assembly-is-part-of-the-net-framework/3666403#3666403) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134/determining-if-an-assembly-is-part-of-the-net-framework/3666403#3666403) useful

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the name, but I'll have to see if this is shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Does the "GlobalAssemblyCache" property qualify for your requirement?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.globalassemblycache.aspx

Propably also depends on how you are loading your assemblies collection. If the above mentioned suggestion doesn't work for you, please clarify that.

Comment: Good approach, but I suspect no; I'm building a third-party library and there could be GAC DLL's I need to inspect, so I would need to include those too.